# Changing datetime format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to concatenate two dataframes, but they each have two columns that are datetime objects.  One is formatted YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS while in the other dataframe it is formateed MM/DD/YEAR HH:mm:SS.  Is there way I can convert one format to the other, I am not picky on which one I end up with in the end.

```
start_time
2018-12-31 23:59:18
```

and

```
start_time
4/1/2017 00:13:24
```

Thanks!

Comment: apply `pd.to_datetime` on the corresponding columns of both dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the format like this

```
import datetime

date_time_str = '2018-12-31 23:59:18'  
date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

date_time_str2 = date_time_obj.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
print(date_time_str2)
```

Output : 
31/12/2018 23:59:18